# - XS1OC - MicroSD card - Raspberry PI2 Model B

Tags: sd-card

I just purchased a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and installed (with no issue) using the original SDcard ( Sandisk 8GB / grey model). However, I tried the same with a SanDisk 32GB (Extreme "Gold color" / Ultra "Grey color") and the system simply doesn't start. I have seen the list of supported sd card and both Extreme and Ultra 32GB seems be supported. Knowing this, I guess best is to install latest Firmware but, can somebody let me know how to proceed.

Comment: How did you prepare the new card?